# Microsoft Excel: Dynamic Data Validation List with Indirect References

Tags: excel

I'm looking to create a data validation list that can dynamically reference a sheet and dynamically populate only the cells that have data in them.

I can make a dynamic data validation list that references an non-dynamic sheet using this formula: **=OFFSET(SHEET_NAME!$A$2,,,COUNTA(SHEET_NAME!$A:$A))**

And I can make a non-dynamic data validation list (Only A2:A25) that dynamically references any sheet where Cell A3 contains the sheet name using this formula: **"=INDIRECT("'"&A3&"'!$A2:$A25")"**

But I have been unable to combine the two to make a dynamic data validation list that can dynamically reference sheets. If anyone has any advice to make the two work together or a better method I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have three worksheets where:

- On worksheet `A`, you have ListA with number 1 to 4 in range `A2:A5`
- On worksheet `B`, you have ListB with a,b,c,d,e in range `A2:A6`
- On worksheet `Result`, in cell `A1` you will input the target sheet name (either A or B), in cell `A3` you will use data validation to display a dynamic drop-down list.
- name the dynamic range as **DynamicList**

The formula you will use for the named range **DynamicList** is

```
=INDIRECT(Result!$A$1&"!A2:A"&COUNTA(INDIRECT(Result!$A$1&"!A:A")))
```

When setting up the data validation in cell `A3` on the `Result` sheet, you will enter the following:
[image: screenshot - data validation]

Then you should be able to change the sheet name in cell `A1` on the `Result` sheet to get a dynamic drop-down list as shown below:

[image: screenshot - dynamic list]